# Hazelcast Distributed Map Heap Size Control

Tags: out-of-memory, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I'm using Hazelcast as embedded Distributed Map in my APIs such as MemTable to accumulate entries before It would send to another storage. My question is :

Can I control the Heap Size using the LocalMapStats object provided for IMap ?

I was reading about that object and I though methods such as getHeapSize() or getOwnedEntryMemoryCost() plus getBackupEntryMemoryCost() maybe could be give me the Memory Cost to compare against a threshold and then decide what to do with the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the heap cost of the Map via the API.  This can also be done easily via the scripting console in Hazelcast management center portal.  The code is as below

```
function findOverallDataSizeImap() {
var objs = hazelcast.getDistributedObjects();
var len = objs.length;
var output='';
var totalSizeInMB=0.0;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
if(objs[i] instanceof com.hazelcast.core.IMap){
output = output+' Name : '+objs[i].getName() +' Size (MB) :'+
(objs[i].getLocalMapStats().getHeapCost()/100000)+' \n';
totalSizeInMB=totalSizeInMB+(objs[i].getLocalMapStats().getHeapCost()/100000);
}
}
output = output + ' Total Size (MB) = ' + totalSizeInMB;
return output;
}
```